# IMAP mail forward and organize suggestion?

Tags: imap

I can't find a solution. I need to filter emails exmaple: if received from example@example.com move to directory(imap) TEST and forward to example2@example.com.

Now I can only achieve this with email clients always on my computer (outlook, thunderbird). Maybe anyone could suggest docker solution, so I could leave it on my Synology NAS.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking: are you looking to run a private mailserver that acts as a "sorting relay" between your public mail server and your mail client?

Comment: It sounds as if you are trying to implement .forward or Sieve using inappropriate tools and finding it difficult. Try using .forward or Sieve instead of an IMAP client.

Comment: How can I use .forward and Sieve? IMAP server is not hosted by me.